# How are character creators/customizers done in other games?(Reference images inside)

Tags: character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What techniques could I use to give players the ability to control certain features, e.g. fatness?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16382/what-techniques-could-i-use-to-give-players-the-ability-to-control-certain-featu)

How are character creators(usually seen in RPGs) done?

Such as, the ability to change almost anything on the character, ranging from the size of the nose to overall height.

Sims also has a fairly indepth one, but I can't find a good screenshot of it.

Do they just store a lot of sub-objects for the body and scale them based on preferences? How would that affect things such as animation, and texturing?

Comment: "Almost anything" is a good clue that there are probably many different techniques at work here, in different combinations depending on the specific aspect being edited. "Morph targets" / "blend shapes" do a lot of the heavy lifting, but for more specific advice it would be good to ask a question targeted to one specific character customization feature in *your* game. Show us an example of your character at two or more extremes of the attribute you want to adjust, and the interface you want to use to adjust it, and we can help you find ways to implement that specific feature.